# recibir parametros por url nodejs

Tags: nodejs, url

me gustaría poder recibir algún parametro por url con nodejs lo he intentado de esta forma:

```
router.get('/events:id', (req,res) => {
var choice = req.params.id;
})
```

sin embargo obtengo este error: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te invito a que edites tu pregunta y puedas postear todo el codigo de tu solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que tengas el escenario que te planteo funcional, deberás instalar express con el comando `npm i -S express` y posterior tener una estructura de código similar a la que te muestro

Como no especificas que tecnologías usas, te comento lo siguiente:

1. Express 4 o superior
2. NodeJS

Dentro de tu archivo app.js escribe lo siguiente:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.get('/about/:name', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World:' + req.params.name)
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Running")
})
```

1. La variable que pasas es con la sintaxis de 2 puntos y el nombre de la misma
2. Para invocarla y poder imprimirla es `req.params.nombre_variable`

> Recuerda que hasta el momento como yo tengo código es necesario
>   reiniciar el servicio cada vez que escribas algo si no los cambios no
>   se verán con el comando `node app.js` o el nombre que le hayas puesto a tu archivo

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

> Si deseas guardar el dato que llega en una variable, solo debes hacer
>   lo siguiente es decir tu código debe lucir similar al siguiente

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.get('/about/:name', (req, res) => {
    const name = req.params.name
    res.send('Hello World:' + name)
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Running")
})
```

> Como puedes notar en el ejemplo anterior, asigno a la constante `name`
>   lo que se recibe por `req` que es el `request` que a su vez lee a
>   `params` y obtiene el valor de la variable que viene por URL llamada
>   `name`